# Laravel API - not working protection for unauthorized users in Postman

Tags: php, laravel, postman

I am learning to create Laravel api. I try to protect my data from not authorized users like: do not permit unauthorized users to get and post data to my app. In the browser it works: If the user does not provide login credentials he does not get anything. In postman I can get all the data without credentials. Why?

```
public function __construct()
{
    $this->middleware('auth.basic');
    //works in browser but not in postman
}
```

Get all the lessons as JSON:

```
public function index()
{
    $lessons =  Lesson::all();

    return $this->respond([
        'data' => $this->transformCollection($lessons->toArray())
    ]);
}
```

Post method: (if I don't give title and body values, I get the 422 response code)

```
public function store()
{
    if (!Input::get('title') or !Input::get('body') ){
        return $this->setStatusCode(422)->respondWithError("Parameters failed validation");
    }

    Lesson::create(Input::all());
    return $this->respondCreated("Successfully created");
}
```

How can I prevent Postman from get and post methods for unauthorized users. Is there a workaround for this?

Comment: do you perhaps forgot to turn of the credentials in postman?

Comment: where do I see it?

Comment: I thing that the problem is not in postman, it should not get any data if I try to get the data as an unauthorized user

Comment: Unless you are :o

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should pass token from postman and validate it.
[Click here to view how to pass token from postman.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PkKJL.png)

```
$this->validate($request, [
     'token' => 'required',
]);
```

And Then

```
    public function index()
    {
        $u = UserSession::where('token',$token)->first();
        if(count($u) > 0) {
            $lessons =  Lesson::all();

            return $this->respond([
                'data' => $this->transformCollection($lessons->toArray())
            ]);
        } else {
            return Api::error(100, $inputs, array("Invalid Token")); 
        }
    }
```